# Search users with custom meta data

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, meta-query, user-meta

I'm looking for a way to search to make wordpress search for matches on a WC users billing-/shipping-company - but im not sure how to achive this.
I found out how i can do it with the most common user fields (ID, login, email & nicename).

Searching for common user data:

```
    $customers_query = new WP_User_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_json_search_customers_query', array(
        'fields'         => 'all',
        'orderby'        => 'display_name',
        'search'         => '*' . $term . '*',
        'search_columns' => array( 'ID', 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_nicename')
    ) ) );
```

I tried also tried:

```
    $yoursearchquery = 'Andr';
    $users = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'search' => $yoursearchquery,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'billing_last_name',
                'value' => $yoursearchquery,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'billing_first_name',
                'value' => $yoursearchquery,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    ));
```

but this only returns if i use the EXACT word i want it to search for - and not part of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
    's' => $yoursearchquery,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'billing_last_name',
            'value' => $yoursearchquery,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'billing_first_name',
            'value' => $yoursearchquery,
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
```